# php replace duplicate values from two strings

Tags: replace

i want to replace similar numbers in two strings please help me how can i do this easily 
strin="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8" 
string2="1,5,8"

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr_1 = explode(',',$strin);
$arr_2 = explode(',',$string2);
$result_array=array_unique( array_merge($arr_1, $arr_2) );
echo implode(',',$result_array);
```